# How do I combine pages (and their templates) into one page?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want the CMS to have the different pages (e.g. "Careers", "Jobs", "Team") with each having its own template, but then to combine them into one big scrollable page (e.g. "Our Company") that would have a template. How would I do this?

I know there *used* to be a function [`get_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page) but that's been deprecated (and replaced with `get_post` which is not the same thing), but that doesn't retrieve the page's template.

1. I want both the page and the template so I can output both into the main page.
2. I also want it so if someone clicks in the navigation menu to go to "Jobs" or "Team", it will take them to that "Our Company" page, but with a querystring so I can scroll them to that part of the page

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

First for main page template choose default template and write you global elements there. And in this template use get_template part to include pages

```
<!--custom query for pages-->
<?php
$args= array('post_type'=>'page');
$query= new WP_Query($args);  
$query->while(have_posts()):query->the_post(); 
 $temp_name= get_page_template_slug( $post->ID );       
 $temp_name_exp =explode('.',$temp_name);
 get_template_part($temp_name_exp[0]); 

endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

and in career, blog etc pages

```
<?php
/*
Template name: Career or blog or something else
*/ 
?>
<?php the_tiele();
      the_content();
 ?>
```

for
"I also want it so if someone clicks in the navigation menu to go to "Jobs" or "Team", it will take them to that "Our Company" page, but with a querystring so I can scroll them to that part of the page"
assign each pages wrapper to page slug example `<section class="<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>">`  and write a function to redirect your view page link to    `http://yoursiteurl/#page-slug`

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

In order to get one page's content into another use the following function:

```
function show_post($path){
 $post = get_page_by_path($path);
 $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
 echo $content;
}
```

and then create a template for the "Our company" page (like `template-our_company.php`) in which you will make a call to the function (e.g. `<?php show_post('careers');  /* Shows the content of the "Careers" page using the slug. */ ?>`).

So the template file should include something like this:

```
<?php
show_post('careers'); 
show_post('jobs'); 
show_post('team'); 
?>
```

For your 2nd question, you need to adjust the template-our_company.php  file like this:

```
<?php
<div id="careers"></div>
show_post('careers'); 
<div id="jobs"></div>
show_post('jobs'); 
<div id="team"></div>
show_post('team'); 
?>
```

and then in the Menu dashboard, just adjust the navigation link to something like "/our-company/#careers" etc.

**EDIT 2**

In order to retrieve the content of pages with specified templates in another template, you can do the following:
Create the templates *(files careers.php and jobs.php)* and the posts that will be using those templates

```
/*
Template Name: Careers
*/
```

...

```
/*
Template Name: Jobs
*/
```

Then in the "parent" template, you can query the posts that have the above specified templates selected
*untested code*

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => '_wp_page_template',
            'value' => 'careers.php',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_wp_page_template',
            'value' => 'jobs.php',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
    the_content();
    // or add anything else
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: thanks! how do I then apply the careers content just to the careers template part? (and the same for the others)

Comment: I edited my answer. Just create the pages as usual, without any template attached to them, then for the "Our company" page use the template I mentioned (template-our_company.php), and follow the instructions above

Comment: that won't work. I need this so that new pages can be added later and have a specific template chosen for that page's content. this is why I want each page to have a template but be able to include that content/template on the combined page. for example, I could add "our superstars" and give it the template "people layout". in your current answer, there's no way to do this. I'd have to manually change the code/template of the combined page.

Comment: Page templates can work only one-way, as the Codex mention, for your website Pages to look about the same (http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) - it provides the structure so that page's content can appear accordingly

Comment: what do you mean they're only one way?

Comment: Means that you can only use to provide the structure of the page that they will be used for, you can't have a template assigned to some page, and then call the template to get the page's content.

Comment: yes, I know. but I should be able to get the template, get the content and then apply the content to the template, then take that output and add it to the page's output.

Answer (score 0):

@user3418748's answer was a good start for me, but in my case I needed to load specific pages, and I found that just using `get_template_part()` by itself wasn't loading any content because I was doing it outside a loop. In order to get this to work you need to first set the global `$post` variable to the page/post you want to display. Here's the function I used (replace `mytemplate` with the name of your tempalte):

```
function mytemplate_show_page($path) {
    global $post;
    $post = get_page_by_path($path);
    $tpl_slug = get_page_template_slug($post->ID);
    $tpl_slug_exp = explode('.', $tpl_slug);
    get_template_part($tpl_slug_exp[0]);
}
```