# Render child page on parent page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, parent-child

How can I render a child page on the parent page in wordpress? I'am building a landing page website, and the idea is to use child pages to make landing page structure.

Now I'am using this code in my parent page template:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'page',
    'post_parent'       => $post->ID,                               
    'orderby'           => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'no_found_rows'     => true
);
$child = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($child->posts);
```

But it just gives me an array, and I need fully rendered HTML of my child pages.

Thank you in advance)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code here:

```
$args = array(
    'hierarchical' => 0,
    'child_of'     => $post->ID,
    'parent'       => $post->ID,
    'sort_column'  => 'menu_order, ID',
);

$pages = get_pages( $args );


foreach ( $pages as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );

   // child page html content here

endforeach;

//reset to the main page
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found the proper solution, inspired by [Matt Browne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38191004/1285387)

functions.php

```
function eatwings_show_page($pageid) 
{
    global $post;
    $post = get_page($pageid);
    $tpl_slug = get_page_template_slug($post->ID);
    $tpl_slug_exp = explode('.', $tpl_slug);
    get_template_part($tpl_slug_exp[0]);
}
```

parent-page-template.php:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'page',
    'post_parent'       => $post->ID,                               
    'orderby'           => 'menu_order, ID',
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'no_found_rows'     => true
);
$child = new WP_Query($args);

foreach($child->posts as $childpage)
{
    eatwings_show_page($childpage->ID);
}
```